# Dark Mode After 1700 hours

Tags: javascript, html, darkmode

I'm trying to change the background and one (1) heading to different colors after a certain time on my webpage (1700 hours). However, it doesn't trigger. What am I doing wrong here?

```js
var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dayLight = 0900;
var lightMode = 1700;


if (time >= dayLight && time <= lightMode) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.querySelector("h1.example").style.color = "black";
    console.log(time + " " + "=" + " " + "Light Mode!");
} else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.querySelector("h1.example").style.color = "white";
    console.log(time + " " + "=" + " " + "Dark Mode!");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Dark Mode Example</title>
    </head>

    <body>
       
        <h1 class="example">Dark Mode Example</h1>
   
        <p>Test Paragraph</p>
    </body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: You check for the date only once; you compare time strings with numbers.

Comment: it's darkmode for me and it's 20:13 here.. ur code's good bru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//I just set an interval for every second to check the time again
var s=setInterval(()=>{
  var today = new Date();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  var dayLight = 0900;
  var lightMode = 1700;


  if (time >= dayLight && time <= lightMode) {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      document.querySelector("h1.example").style.color = "black";
      //console.log(time + " " + "=" + " " + "Light Mode!");
  } else {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
      document.querySelector("h1.example").style.color = "white";
      //console.log(time + " " + "=" + " " + "Dark Mode!");
  }
},1000)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Dark Mode Example</title>
    </head>

    <body>
       
        <h1 class="example">Dark Mode Example</h1>
   
        <p>Test Paragraph</p>
    </body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```